# How can I publish my aar to bintray and prevent users from seeing the source?

Tags: android, gradle, obfuscation, bintray, jcenter

I have created a bintray repository that has a package in it. When I publish my library and reference it from another project I am able to see my source code. On the other hand if I build aar and import it to my other projects directly the code is obfuscated. I would like to achieve the same effect on published libraries in jCenter. Is that possible?

```
bintray {
user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

pkg {
    repo = bintrayRepo
    name = bintrayName
    desc = libraryDescription
    websiteUrl = siteUrl
    vcsUrl = gitUrl
    licenses = allLicenses
    dryRun = false
    publish = true
    override = false
    publicDownloadNumbers = true
    version {
        name = libraryVersion
        desc = libraryDescription
    }
}
```

EDIT: I am not running javadocJar and sourcesJar gradle tasks

Comment: You are probably inadvertently publishing the source JAR along with the AAR.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman I have updated my post

Comment: You MUST be publishing the source. The only other possibility is that bintray has become self aware and is hacking into your computer to find your source code.

Comment: Bintray also offers private repositories.